# powershell string replace inline or new loop

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Whats the best way to do some string replacements in the 'fullname'?

something like `.Replace($oldString, $newString)` but it needs to be done after the MD5 is already calculated.

Or is it just better to do another ForEach-Object after my MD5 process is done?

```
| select-object name, fullname, @{Name = "MD5"; Expression = { (Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5).Hash.ToLower() } }
```

Comment: In your `Select-Object` call, you can replace `fullname` with another [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties), along the lines of `@{ Name='FullName'; Expression={$_.FullName.Replace($oldString, $newString } }`

Comment: `| select-object name, fullname, @{Name = "MD5"; Expression 
= { (Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5).Hash.ToLower() } } @{ Name='FullName'; Expression={ $_.FullName.Replace($oldString, $newString) } }`

results in an error Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Collections.Hashtable'.

Comment: That's because (a) _fundamentally_, the property names / calculated-property hashtable definitions passed to `Select-Object`'s `-Property` parameter must be passed as an _array_, which means that they must be _separated with `,`_. However, (b), _specifically_, as my first comment implies, `@{ Name='FullName'; Expression={ $_.FullName.Replace($oldString, $newString) } }` should be used _instead of_ `fullname`. However, if you do need the `.FullName` property to retain its original value in a subsequent processing step first, you indeed need  to defer the  transformation until later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it needs to be done after the MD5 is already calculated

I don't think you can depend on another calculated property when creating a calculated property, at least not within the same pipeline step. Each calculated property will only be available when the current pipeline step has finished as a whole.

What you could do is chain two `Select-Object` statements like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -file |
select-object fullname, name, @{Name = "MD5"; Expression = { (Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5).Hash.ToLower() } } | 
select-object name, MD5, @{Name = 'fullname'; Expression = { <# do something with $_.fullname and $_.MD5 #> }}
```